# How to read TIFF header File c#?

Tags: c#, header, tiff

I wanna know how it is possible to read a file in binary format.

for example a tiff image file may have the following binary format in hex 0000 4949 002A 0000.
how can i get these values in c#?

Comment: `byte[] buf = new byte[???]; File.Open("somefile").Read(buf,0,buf.Length);`

Comment: I tried this snippet and it worked

Comment: FYI - this is not the correct header format for TIFF.  It may be either 49 49 2a 00 (Intel byte ordering) or 4d 4d 00 2a (Motorola byte ordering), and not what you have in your question.

Comment: i knew that so i need to read the binary format so i can find out about ordering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I usually read files in hexadecimal format, changed for the header, as you need:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace FileToHex
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //read only 4 bytes from the file

            const int HEADER_SIZE = 4;

            byte[] bytesFile = new byte[HEADER_SIZE];

            using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(@"C:\temp\FileToHex\ex.tiff"))
            {
                fs.Read(bytesFile, 0, HEADER_SIZE);
                fs.Close();
            }

            string hex = BitConverter.ToString(bytesFile);

            string[] header = hex.Split(new Char[] { '-' }).ToArray();

            Console.WriteLine(System.String.Join("", header));

            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes() function reads the whole file. I'm searching for a way to read limited number of bytes.

Comment: `string str =  bytesFile.Aggregate("",(s,b)=>s+=b.ToString("X2"));`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ReadAllBytes method of the System.IO.File class to read the bytes into an array:

```
System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(@"C:\Temp\sample.pdf", System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
int size = 1024;
byte[] b = new byte[size];
fs.Read(b, 0, size);
```

Comment: what if the file size is large (e.g more than 300 megabytes). is there any way to limit number of bytes to be read?

Comment: System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes() function reads the whole file. I'm searching for a way to read limited number of bytes.

Comment: @AmirJalali Use a file stream to read one character at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I have not used LibTIFF.Net, http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff but it seems to be fairly complete.

Using it, instead of reading the file as bytes and then decoding the header(s) may be a lot easier for you.

Comment: I'm using LibTIFF.Net now but i couldn't find anything that can show the "byte order" in a TIFF header file.