# How to read TIFF File headers in c?

Tags: c, header, tags, binary, tiff

How can i read a tiff file header in c ?

actually i want to learn TIFF Tag ImageWidth, and TIFF Tag ImageLength.

how can i acces this attributes?

http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/imagewidth.html
http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/imagelength.html

the c translation of this code can help me :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9071933/2079158

i don't know c well,
 tried something like this :

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

main()
{
FILE* f = fopen("tifo.tif", "rb");
unsigned char info[500];
fread(info, sizeof(unsigned char), 500, f); 

long int width = *(long int*)&info[256];
short int height = *(short int*)&info[257];

printf("width : %d \n", width);
printf("height : %d \n", height);

fclose(f);
}
```

what can i do for tiff files??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve th problem with this code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "tiffio.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>     
int main(void)
{
DIR *dp;
struct dirent *ep;
uint32 w, h;
float xdpi,ydpi;

dp = opendir ("./");
char file_name[30];
char last[30];
if (dp != NULL)
{
    while (ep = readdir (dp))
    {
        if( ( strstr(ep->d_name, ".tif") != NULL ) || ( strstr(ep->d_name, ".TIF") != NULL ) )
        {
            TIFF* tif = TIFFOpen(ep->d_name, "r");
            TIFFGetField(tif, TIFFTAG_IMAGEWIDTH, &w);
            TIFFGetField(tif, TIFFTAG_IMAGELENGTH, &h);
            TIFFGetField(tif, TIFFTAG_XRESOLUTION, &xdpi);
            TIFFGetField(tif, TIFFTAG_YRESOLUTION, &ydpi);

            printf("%s --> %d x %d | %.f - %.f \n",ep->d_name, w, h, xdpi,ydpi);

            strncpy ( file_name, ep->d_name, ep->d_namlen-4 );
            file_name[ep->d_namlen-4]='\0';

            sprintf(last,"%s (%.f x %.f).tif", file_name, (float) ((w/xdpi)*2.54) , (float) ((h/ydpi)*2.54) );
            printf("      |__ %s\n\n",last);
            TIFFClose(tif);

            rename(ep->d_name, last);
        }
    }
    (void) closedir (dp);
}
else
    perror ("Directory can not open!");

printf("Succesfully finished!");
getchar();

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is trying to read a header with offsets. That's not how TIFF works. It has a short header, which identifies where a "image file directory" (IFD) starts. The IFD contains one or more entries, each of which has a TAG explaining what its content is, a field type, a count and an offset to the value itself.

To find the size of the image, you need to scan the relevant IFD's for the tag that has value 256 and 257 respectively.

This is explained in much more detail here:
http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/tiff/index.html#spec

I would suggest that you look at a tiff compatible image library, tho', as it gets pretty complex pretty quickly to read a TIFF file - they have all manner of compressed formats and such, which makes it quite a lot of work to implement a complete reader for TIFF's.

Answer (score 0):

You are mis-interpreting the "tag IDs" (256 and 257) as indexes, that won't work.

You need to search for the required IDs in the file, and then extract the value associated with each ID.

Note that TIFF doesn't have a "header" that contains all the information, you will need to seek through the file to find what you're after.

Comment: but how :( 
am i reading all the header with "fread(info, sizeof(unsigned char), 500, f); " and how will i search IDs??